# JavaFX ListChangeListener handles 'removeAll(Collection)' inconsistently based on position of removed items in ObservableList

Tags: javafx, observablelist, changelistener

I've encountered what appears to be an anomaly in how `ListChangeListener` handles batch removals (i.e. `removeAll(Collection)`. If the items in the `Collection` are *contiguous* then the handling operation specified in the listener works fine. However, if the `Collection` are *not* contiguous then the operation specified in the listener halts once *contiguity* is broken.

This can best be explained by way of example. Assume the `ObservableList` consists of the following items:

- "red"
- "orange"
- "yellow"
- "green"
- "blue"

Assume also that there is a separate `ObservableList` that tracks the `hashCode` values for the colors, and that a `ListChangeListener` has been added that removes the `hashCode` from the second list whenever one or more of the items in the first list is removed. If the 'removal' `Collection` consists of "red", "orange" and "yellow" then the code in the listener removes the `hashCodes` for all three items from the second list as expected. However, if the 'removal' `Collection` consists of "red", "orange" and "*green*", then the code in the listener stops after removing the `hashCode` for "orange" and never reaches "green" like it should.

A short app that illustrates the problem is set out below. The listener code is in a method named `buildListChangeListener()` that returns a listener that is added to the 'Colors' list. To run the app it helps to know that:

- 'consecutive' in the `ComboBox` specifies three colors that are *contiguous* as explained above; clicking the 'Remove' button will cause them to be removed from the 'Colors' list and their `hashCodes`
  from the other list.
- 'broken' specifies three colors that are not *contiguous*, so that
  clicking the 'Remove' button removes only one of the colors
- clicking 'Refresh' restores both lists to their original state

Here's the code for the app:

```
    package test;

import static java.util.Objects.isNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;
import javafx.util.Pair;

public class RemoveAllItemsBug extends Application {

     private StackPane stackPane;
     private HBox hbox;

     private VBox vbox1;
     private Label label1;
     private ListView<Pair<String, Color>> colors;

     private VBox vbox2;
     private Label label2;
     private ListView<Integer> hashCodes;

     private VBox vbox3;
     private Label label3;
     private ComboBox<String> actionModes;
     private Button btnRemove;
     private Button btnRefresh;

     final static private String CONSECUTIVE = "consecutive", BROKEN = "broken";

     private final EventHandler<WindowEvent> onCloseRequestListener = evt -> {
          Platform.exit();
          System.exit(0);
     };

     @Override
     public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
          primaryStage.setTitle("DUMMY  APP");

          // Necessary to ensure stage closes completely and javaw.exe stops running
          primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(onCloseRequestListener);

          primaryStage.setWidth(550);
          primaryStage.setHeight(310);

          //          primaryStage.setMinWidth(550);
          //          primaryStage.setMinHeight(310);

          /*
           * Code block below for width/height property printouts is used to
           * test for an optimal size for the app. Once the size is determined
           * they may (and should be) commented out as here.
           */
          primaryStage
                      .widthProperty()
                      .addListener((width, oldWidth, newWidth) -> {
                           System.out.println("width: " + newWidth);
                      });

          primaryStage
                      .heightProperty()
                      .addListener((height, oldHeight, newHeight) -> {
                           System.out.println("height: " + newHeight);
                      });

          initializeUI();
          installSimpleBehavior();
          installListChangeListener();

          primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane));
          primaryStage.show();
     }

     private void installListChangeListener() {
          /*
           * The 'listChangeListenerUsingIf()' method returns a listener that
           * uses an 'if (c.next()) ...' statement to access the first change in
           * the Change variable (c). For purposes of accessing the first change
           * this is functionally equivalent to a 'while (c.next()) ...'
           * statement. However, because the Change variable may contain
           * multiple 'remove' changes where each change is represented by a
           * separate 'getRemoved()' list, the 'if (c.next())' statement will
           * catch only the first change while the 'while (c.next())' statement
           * (which is used in the 'listChangeListenerUsingWhile()' method)
           * catches them all.
           * 
           * The code below should be commented out as appropriate before
           * running the app in order to see the difference.
           * 
           * This case illustrates a serious flaw in the ListChangeListener API
           * documentation because it fails to indicate that the Change variable
           * may include multiple 'remove' changes and that each such change
           * must be accessed in a separate iteration (e.g. the 'while
           * (c.next()...').
           * 
           * In contrast, 'add' changes (i.e. changes resulting from the
           * addition of one or more items to the source list), the name of the
           * method that returns the change(s) is 'getAddSublist()'. This
           * clearly indicates that there may be more than one list of items
           * that have been added, or similarly that the total items that have
           * been 'added' by the change(s) represented by the Change variable
           * may be included in more than one list; thus the use of the term
           * 'sublist'.
           * 
           * The flaw is illustrated further in the cautionary note in the API
           * that reads as follows:
           * 
           * "[I]n case the change contains multiple changes of different type,
           * these changes must be in the following order: <em> permutation
           * change(s), add or remove changes, update changes </em> This is
           * because permutation changes cannot go after add/remove changes as
           * they would change the position of added elements. And on the other
           * hand, update changes must go after add/remove changes because they
           * refer with their indexes to the current state of the list, which
           * means with all add/remove changes applied."
           * 
           * This is certainly useful information. However, the problems
           * illustrated by the case at hand (i.e. different treatment based on
           * whether the changed items are continguous in the source list) are
           * just as significant as the situation addressed by the note, yet
           * they are not mentioned.
           * 
           * A better understanding as to how the process works can be gained by
           * running a system printout for the Change variable class
           * (System.out.println("Change variable class: " +
           * c.getClass().getSimpleName())) and compare the results yielded from
           * changing the choice in the 'Action modes' combo box from
           * 'consecutive' to 'broken'. For 'consecutive' (i.e. continguous),
           * the class for the Change variable is
           * ListChangeBuilder$SingleChange, for 'broken' (i.e. non-continguous)
           * the class is ListChangeBuilder$IterableChange. These classes aren't
           * well documented, which while regrettable is understandable inasmuch
           * as they're private inner classes for restricted API. Interestingly,
           * however, there is a public class MultipleAdditionAndRemovedChange
           * (also restricted API) that appears to fit this case perfectly and
           * is a bit more informative.
           */

          //          colors.getItems().addListener(listChangeListenerUsingIf());
          colors.getItems().addListener(listChangeListenerUsingWhile());
     }

     private void initializeUI() {

          //- Controls for colors
          label1 = new Label("Colors");
          colors = new ListView<Pair<String, Color>>();
          colors.setPrefSize(150, 200);
          colors.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<>(colorsList())));
          vbox1 = new VBox(label1, colors);

          //- Controls for colors
          label2 = new Label("Hash codes");
          hashCodes = new ListView<Integer>();
          hashCodes.setPrefSize(150, 200);
          hashCodes.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<>(
                                                                          colorsList().stream()
                                                                                      .map(e -> e.hashCode())
                                                                                      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)))));
          vbox2 = new VBox(label2, hashCodes);

          //- 'Action mode' controls
          label3 = new Label("Action mode");
          actionModes = new ComboBox<>(
                                       FXCollections.observableList(List.of(CONSECUTIVE, BROKEN)));
          actionModes.setPrefWidth(150);
          actionModes.getSelectionModel().select(0);
          btnRemove = new Button("Remove");
          btnRefresh = new Button("Refresh");
          List.of(btnRemove, btnRefresh).forEach(b -> {
               b.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
               VBox.setMargin(b, new Insets(5, 0, 0, 0));
          });
          vbox3 = new VBox(label3, actionModes, btnRemove, btnRefresh);

          hbox = new HBox(vbox1, vbox2, vbox3);
          hbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
          hbox.setSpacing(15);
          hbox.setBackground(new Background(
                                            new BackgroundFill(Color.DARKGRAY, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY),
                                            new BackgroundFill(Color.WHITESMOKE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, new Insets(1))));

          stackPane = new StackPane(hbox);
          stackPane.setPadding(new Insets(15));
     }

     private void installSimpleBehavior() {

          //- 'Colors' cell factory
          colors.setCellFactory(listView -> {
               return new ListCell<Pair<String, Color>>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Pair<String, Color> item, boolean empty) {
                         super.updateItem(item, empty);
                         if (isNull(item) || empty) {
                              setGraphic(null);
                              setText(null);
                         }
                         else {
                              HBox graphic = new HBox();
                              graphic.setPrefSize(15, 15);
                              graphic.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(
                                                                                      item.getValue(),
                                                                                      CornerRadii.EMPTY,
                                                                                      Insets.EMPTY)));
                              setGraphic(graphic);
                              setText(item.getKey());
                              setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);
                         }
                    }
               };
          });

          //- 'Colors' cell factory
          hashCodes.setCellFactory(listView -> {
               return new ListCell<Integer>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                         super.updateItem(item, empty);
                         if (isNull(item) || empty) {
                              setGraphic(null);
                              setText(null);
                         }
                         else {
                              HBox graphic = new HBox();
                              graphic.setPrefSize(15, 15);
                              graphic.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(
                                                                                      colorForHashCode(item),
                                                                                      CornerRadii.EMPTY,
                                                                                      Insets.EMPTY)));
                              Canvas c = new Canvas(15, 15);
                              GraphicsContext graphics = c.getGraphicsContext2D();
                              graphics.setFill(colorForHashCode(item));
                              graphics.fillRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
                              setGraphic(c);
                              setText("" + item);
                              setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);
                         }
                    }

                    private Color colorForHashCode(int hash) {
                         return colorsList().stream()
                                            .filter(e -> e.hashCode() == hash)
                                            .map(e -> e.getValue())
                                            .findFirst()
                                            .orElseThrow();
                    }
               };
          });

          //- 'Remove' button action
          btnRemove.setOnAction(e -> {
               String actionMode = actionModes.getValue();
               if (CONSECUTIVE.equals(actionMode)) {
                    colors.getItems().removeAll(consecutiveColors());
               }
               else if (BROKEN.equals(actionMode)) {
                    colors.getItems().removeAll(brokenColors());
               }
          });

          //- 'Refresh' button action
          btnRefresh.setOnAction(e -> {
               colors.getItems().setAll(colorsList());
               hashCodes.getItems().setAll(colorsList()
                                                       .stream()
                                                       .map(ee -> ee.hashCode())
                                                       .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
          });
     }

     private ListChangeListener<Pair<String, Color>> listChangeListenerUsingIf() {
          return c -> {
               if (c.next()) {
                    System.out.println("Change variable class: " + c.getClass().getName());
                    if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                         System.out.println("Removing " + c.getRemovedSize() + " items");
                         c.getRemoved().forEach(e -> {
                              Integer hash = Integer.valueOf(e.hashCode());
                              hashCodes.getItems().remove(hash);
                         });
                         System.out.println("number of 'hash codes' after removal: " + hashCodes.getItems().size());
                         System.out.println();
                    }
                    if (c.wasAdded()) {
                         c.getAddedSubList().forEach(e -> {
                              if (hashCodes.getItems().stream().noneMatch(ee -> ee == e.hashCode()))
                                   hashCodes.getItems().add(e.hashCode());
                         });
                    }
               }
          };
     }

     private ListChangeListener<Pair<String, Color>> listChangeListenerUsingWhile() {
          return c -> {
               while (c.next()) {
                    System.out.println("Change variable class: " + c.getClass().getName());
                    if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                         System.out.println("Removing " + c.getRemovedSize() + " items");
                         c.getRemoved().forEach(e -> {
                              Integer hash = Integer.valueOf(e.hashCode());
                              hashCodes.getItems().remove(hash);
                         });
                         System.out.println("number of 'hash codes' after removal: " + hashCodes.getItems().size());
                         System.out.println();
                    }
                    if (c.wasAdded()) {
                         c.getAddedSubList().forEach(e -> {
                              if (hashCodes.getItems().stream().noneMatch(ee -> ee == e.hashCode()))
                                   hashCodes.getItems().add(e.hashCode());
                         });
                    }
               }
          };
     }

     private List<Pair<String, Color>> colorsList() {
          return List.of(
                         new Pair<>("rot", Color.RED),
                         new Pair<>("orange", Color.ORANGE),
                         new Pair<>("gelb", Color.YELLOW),
                         new Pair<>("grün", Color.GREEN),
                         new Pair<>("blau", Color.BLUE),
                         new Pair<>("violett", Color.PURPLE),
                         new Pair<>("grau", Color.GRAY),
                         new Pair<>("schwarz", Color.BLACK));
     }

     private List<Pair<String, Color>> consecutiveColors() {
          return List.of(
                         new Pair<>("gelb", Color.YELLOW),
                         new Pair<>("grün", Color.GREEN),
                         new Pair<>("blau", Color.BLUE));
     }

     private List<Pair<String, Color>> brokenColors() {
          return List.of(
                         new Pair<>("rot", Color.RED),
                         new Pair<>("grün", Color.GREEN),
                         new Pair<>("blau", Color.BLUE));
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          launch(args);
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

[Edit in view of @Slaw's first comment]

This case raises several problems. @Slaw's first comment caused me to look at this differently. @Slaw is right in pointing out that using a `while (c.next()) ...` clause fixes the problem that is caused when a `if (c.next())...` clause is used.

When this is viewed holistically, however, there is more fundamental problem the led not so much to the use of the `if (c.next())` clause, but disguised that error and made it very difficult to discover. This problem is the abysmal documentation for the `ListChangeListener` class.

I've modified the code for the sample app to include a second listener method that works properly (with a name change to the one that generated the error), together a comment as to why it was necessary and how the `ListChangeListener` and more particularly its `Change` companion, seem to work. The relevant parts of that comment are repeated below:

The `listChangeListenerUsingIf()` method returns a listener that uses an `if (c.next()) ...` statement to access the first change in the `Change` variable (c). For purposes of accessing the first change this is functionally equivalent to a `while (c.next()) ...` statement. However, because the `Change` variable may contain multiple 'remove' changes where each change is represented by a separate `getRemoved()` list, the `if (c.next())` statement will catch only the first change while the `while (c.next())` statement (which is used in the `listChangeListenerUsingWhile()` method) catches them all.

This case illustrates a serious flaw in the `ListChangeListener` API documentation because it fails to indicate that the `Change` variable may include multiple 'remove' changes and that each such change must be accessed in a separate iteration (e.g. the `while (c.next()...`).

In contrast, for 'add' changes (i.e. changes resulting from the addition of one or more items to the source list) the name of the method that returns the change(s) is `getAddedSublist()`. This clearly indicates that there may be more than one list of items that have been added, or similarly that the total items that have been 'added' by the change(s) represented by the `Change` variable may be included in more than one list; thus the use of the term `sublist`.

The flaw is illustrated further in the cautionary note in the API that reads as follows:

"[I]n case the change contains multiple changes of different type, these changes must be in the following order:  *permutation change(s), add or remove changes, update changes*  This is because permutation changes cannot go after add/remove changes as they would change the position of added elements. And on the other hand, update changes must go after add/remove changes because they refer with their indexes to the current state of the list, which means with all add/remove changes applied."

This is certainly useful information. However, the problems illustrated by the case at hand (i.e. different treatment based on whether the changed items are continguous in the source list) are just as significant as the situation addressed by the note; yet they are not mentioned.

A better understanding as to how the process works can be gained by running a system printout for the `Change` variable class (`System.out.println("Change variable class: " + c.getClass().getSimpleName())`) and compare the results yielded from changing the choice in the 'Action modes' combo box from 'consecutive' to 'broken'. For 'consecutive' (i.e. *continguous*), the class for the `Change` variable is `ListChangeBuilder$SingleChange`, for 'broken' (i.e. *non-continguous*) the class is `ListChangeBuilder$IterableChange`. These classes aren't well documented, which while regrettable is understandable inasmuch as they're private inner classes for restricted API. Interestingly, however, there is a public class `MultipleAdditionAndRemovedChange` (also restricted API) that appears to fit this case perfectly and is a bit more informative.

I hope this helps, and thanks to @Slaw for the useful input.

Comment: @Abra - there was indeed a problem with back ticks etc., they were fixed within minutes after the question was first posted. As of this comment I see no issues in that regard. As for your statement re `ListChangeListener` not having a `removeAll()` method, the question describes a problem where that method (as a `List` method, `Observable` or otherwise) is used; there is nothing about a `ListChangeListener` method having that name. Running the sample code illustrates the problem.

Comment: just to emphasize: `if (c.next() ..` used in part of the code is __plain wrong__ .. future readers, ignore ;)

Comment: @kleopatra, while the comments relating to the answer would seem to say the same thing that is clearly not the case, so thanks again for being so helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`ListChangeListener.Change`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html):

> Represents a report of changes done to an `ObservableList`. **The change may consist of one or more actual changes and must be iterated by calling the `next()` method** *[emphasis added]*.

In your implementation of `ListChangeListener` you have:

```java
if (c.next()) {
  // handle change...
}
```

This will only process a single change. You need to *loop* over (i.e. iterate) the changes in case there are multiple:

```java
while (c.next()) {
 // handle change...
}
```

Simply changing that one `if` to a `while` in your example fixes the problem you describe.

Here's an example showing how a bulk removal of non-contiguous elements results in multiple changes coalesced into a single `ListChangeListener.Change` object:

```java
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
    list.addListener(
        (ListChangeListener<Integer>)
            c -> {
              System.out.println("----------BEGIN_CHANGE----------");
              while (c.next()) {
                // for example, assume c.wasRemoved() returns true
                System.out.printf(
                    "Removed %d element(s): %s%n", c.getRemovedSize(), c.getRemoved());
              }
              System.out.println("-----------END_CHANGE-----------");
            });
    list.removeAll(1, 7, 3, 8, 2, 10);
  }
}
```

And the output:

```
----------BEGIN_CHANGE----------
Removed 3 element(s): [1, 2, 3]
Removed 2 element(s): [7, 8]
Removed 1 element(s): [10]
-----------END_CHANGE-----------
```

If you're familiar with JDBC you'll notice the API for iterating a `ListChangeListener.Change` is similar to iterating a `ResultSet`.

Comment: I am VERY grateful for your reply, mostly b/c I tried to 'comment' back to you on another question I asked recently to which you (and @Kleopatra) replied and which is still remains unresolved. There is a matter unrelated to this question that I need to discuss with you via a chat which I can't open on my own and would need your assistance. It's the middle of the night where I live, I just checked my messages on my way back from the bathroom :) and saw this.

Comment: @ slaw on your reply here, did you notice that the handling in the listener does iterate through the 'removed' list, albeit by using the `.forEach(e->...)` technique? In the actual class where this problem comes up (it's a library project) the `c.wasRemoved()` method returns multiple items, and everything works fine so long as the items are *contiguous* in the `ObservableList`; it's only when there's a break in the *continguity* that the problem arises.

Comment: Your listener is iterating over the removed elements of only **one of the changes**. You need to iterate over each _change_ and query what the change is. That's what the `while (c.next())` does. Take a look at the example at the end of my answer again. I remove, using a _single_ `removeAll` call, a group of non-contiguous elements yet the output shows all those elements removed reported in a _single_ `Change` object. The first `c.next()` reports a removal of `[1, 2, 3]`, the second `c.next()` reports a removal of `[7, 8]`, and the last `c.next()` reports a removal of `[10]`.

Comment: And as stated, simply changing `if (c.next())` to `while (c.next())` solves the problem described in your question.

Comment: To perhaps make it even clearer: Specifically for a remove-all operation of non-contiguous elements, each time you call `c.next()` and it returns `true` then `c.getRemoved()` **returns a _different_ `List` covering a different "sub-range" of _contiguous_ elements** that were removed (where each sub-range has one or more elements).

Comment: Thanks for you input. As you point out the original problem is caused by using `if (c.next())` instead of `while (c.next())`. This created a lot of confusion and resulted in many hours of lost time because these two are functionally identical for purposes of accessing the `Change` object, and where the items are contiguous (as they often are) the results are also the same. The real problem lies in the documentation for `ListChangeListener`, or to be more accurate the lack thereof. The original question has been edited to discuss this and other info that is related and hopefully helpful.

Comment: I agree that much of JavaFX could be better documented (some of it seems haphazard, even if it gets the point across). However, while the documentation of `ListChangeListener` may not give much explanation, the bit of documentation of `ListChangeListener.Change` I quoted at the start of my answer does at least imply you need to call `next()` repeatedly until it returns `false`. The same documentation also gives a "typical usage" example. But again, I agree it could be more emphasized.

Comment: Thanks again for you help. On documentation this is a no-brainer, with all due respect. It's clear now how the process works, but *only* after a lot of searching and digging around and trial-and-error, which should not have been necessary. It's clear now that *contiguity* plays a big role in how a `Change` is handled, but the documentation is silent on this. Consider someone who's not as persistent (stubborn?) as I am who had the same problem. They would've quit, maybe stopped using JavaFX and moved to something else, ... all b/c of horsesh*t documentation, ... and not only here.

Comment: @jfr every half-way reasonable tutorial on how-to list to list content changes (including the java doc!) uses the `while (c.next()) { ..}` pattern - so I would expect even a newbie doing the same (and dig a bit into the "why" to understand what's going on: writing tests, reading examples, reading the source code ... whatever). And if they quit, well .. *shrugs

Comment: @jfr Again, I agree some of the documentation is bad. But to be fair, the handling of contiguity or non-contiguity is an _implementation detail_. The implementation of `ObservableList` is free to either coalesce such changes into a single `Change` object (as the current core implementations do) or fire multiple `Change` objects. From an API perspective the only important thing is that you use `while (c.next())` since that will properly address whatever approach is used by the implementation.

Comment: @kleopatra Thank you for your comments, they're most helpful.